# How to send file from one page to another in php

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm making a classified website where the user adds his information for his add and has the option of adding an image. The information from this page then gets sent to another page where the user verifies the information is correct. Then the information gets sent to the last page where it enters the database via prepared statements. So i need to send this file to multiple pages. I tried sending this as follow

```
 $img = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
```

However the binary source of the image escapes the value attribute and I see the binary code being displayed. I don't want this. I was then told to use **move_upload_file** but I dont understand how this can help me. I can add the image to a directory but how do I get the file into the other pages that I need? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: After putting the file in the directory, in the other page just save the reference to file in a hidden field. `<input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $newFilename;?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

The idea to use move_upload_file is that you save a temporal copy from file in your server.

And after if the process ends ok hold the image in your server if not only delete

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

### This is some code I recently used on a project

#### Beware there is absolutely no security implementation in this code

```
$uploaded = array();

if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $position => $name){


        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$position], 'uploads/'.$name)){
            $uploaded[] = array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'file' => 'uploads/'.$name
                );
        }//if
    }//foreach
}//if
```

---

#### The idea of this is to be able to see files that have been uploaded to the `[file]` array in the `$_FILES[]` superglobal, into a directory in the server called `uploads/`. It uses a foreach loop to iterate through each of the files which would appear in your case, in the `[image]` array, and it will move then with the `move_uploaded_file()` method from the temporary superglobal location, to a specified destination on the server.

`move_uploaded_file(tmp_place, destination);`

Comment: If needed, you can write some more code in the inner if statement to either hold on or delete that specified image from the files superglobal so you can pass it into other pages, or just delete it from the temporary place in that array.